# Plane ticket no longer available for the exact day of our visa

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

When applying for the Schengen visa, we were asked to just reserve our airline tickets. The visa process took much longer than they expected and the reservations were cancelled.

Today we were told we could go pick up our visa tomorrow, as long as we purchase and present to them our airline tickets. Like the title says, the problem is they are no longer available for the days we originally requested.

Our visa begins 30 of June, and ends 27 of Sept. We found airline tickets for our destination leaving the 29 of June, and it's an overnight flight, so we would be arriving at our destination on the 30 of June still.

Would we be able to use those tickets with our visa? Or would they stop us at departure at our airport on the 29th, because the visa says the 30th?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the entry date to the country matches the visa requirements you will be okay - the airline knows when they will land there, so will know that by the time you present to immigration, the visa will be valid.

Comment: and the visa allows you to arrive no earlier than the 30th, but if you arrive later, it is still valid (you can enter before the visa expires). So you could still book a ticket for a later day.